# Test whether a user is a fan of a page using the Javascript SDK without permissions?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

Are you able to test whether a user is a fan of a page using the Facebook Javascript SDK without the user granting permissions? All I need is to see whether the user is a fan, if so redirect them to another page. I can do this server side using the C# Facebook SDK, without the user granting permissions.

The reason I am asking is, sometimes it is tedious creating a simple MVC app just so I can test whether the user is a fan of the page. If I can do this with the JS SDK, this will save me an enormous amount of time.

Thanks

Tyrone

Answer (score 1):

the only way to do this (with out permissions) is to parse the [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) that is passed to your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by Javascript SDK of Facebook via parsing signed_request

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
  } else {
    // no user session available, someone you dont know
  }
});
```

It returns a JSON array with signed_request. And after parsing signed request in javascript, you can get user info array which includes page like as **isLiked**.

For more information about API call: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: if you parse the `signed_request` in javascript your `app_secret` will have to be within the javascript scope.  This is a bad idea - you do not want to be giving away your `app_secret`